# RegEx to parse a line from a log file

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a jenkins log file that spits the following output:

> angularjs@1_4_7-ie8 found in path(s):
> public/components/angularjs-ie8-build/dist/angular.min.js
>
> [INFO] Registered manifest into PaaS:
> https://deploy-apixyz.com/swdeploy/v2/manifests/demonodeserver/versions/1.0.0_20180628165604811
>
> Your build metrics have been recorded with id
> demonodeserver-06-29T00:07:42.845Z and manifest_id
> demonodeserver-1.0.0_20180628165604811

I am interested in the `maniest_id` part `demonodeserver-1.0.0_20180628165604811`

I am looking to see if i can write a regex that can parse this.

Tried various methods but failed. Can someone enlighten me?

`str.match(\[demonodeserver-\] (.*))` but this doesn't return valid result.

Comment: `s.match(/demonodeserver-(\S+)/)[1]` or just `s.match(/demonodeserver-\S+/)`

Answer (score 2):

In order to extract `demonodeserver-1.0.0_20180628165604811` from your logs based on your needs, you have several options:

```js
const log = `
angularjs@1_4_7-ie8 found in path(s): public/components/angularjs-ie8-build/dist/angular.min.js

[INFO] Registered manifest into CMPaaS: https://deploy-apixyz.com/swdeploy/v2/manifests/demonodeserver/versions/1.0.0_20180628165604811

Your build metrics have been recorded with id demonodeserver-06-29T00:07:42.845Z and manifest_id demonodeserver-1.0.0_20180628165604811
`;

// If you need the tag part only:
const patternTagOnly = /manifest_id\s+\w+-([\w:\.]+)/m;
const tag = log.match(patternTagOnly)[1];
console.log(`tag only: ${tag}`);

// If you need the name part only:
const patternNameOnly = /manifest_id\s+(\w+)-[\w:\.]+/m;
const name = log.match(patternNameOnly)[1];
console.log(`name only: ${name}`);

// If you need the name and tag part too, unseparated:
const patternFull = /manifest_id\s+(\w+-[\w:\.]+)/m;
const full = log.match(patternFull)[1];
console.log(`full: ${full}`);

// If you need the name and tag part too, but separated:
const patternFullSeparated = /manifest_id\s+(\w+)-([\w:\.]+)/m;
const parts = log.match(patternFullSeparated);
console.log(`full, separated: ${parts[1]} - ${parts[2]}`);
```

To create/test regexes for JavaScript, check out [**regex101**](https://regex101.com/), but make sure you choose the **JavaScript Flavor** regex.

Answer (score 2):

A regex is created with `/`, not `\`. There's also no space in your log output (after demonodeserver-1.0.0), and to get the id I'd also specify which line exactly you're interested in. The following should do the job

```js
const str = `angularjs@1_4_7-ie8 found in path(s):
public/components/angularjs-ie8-build/dist/angular.min.js

[INFO] Registered manifest into CMPaaS:
https://deploy-apixyz.com/swdeploy/v2/manifests/demonodeserver/versions/1.0.0_20180628165604811

Your build metrics have been recorded with id
demonodeserver-06-29T00:07:42.845Z and manifest_id
demonodeserver-1.0.0_20180628165604811`;

const regex = /demonodeserver-(\d\.?){3}_\w+/gm;

const match = str.match(regex);
console.log(match);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in the `manifest_id` part, match on that instead of expecting the actual id to have a constant prefix (you're not always going to be using a demo node server, right?):

```js
const log = `angularjs@1_4_7-ie8 found in path(s): public/components/angularjs-ie8-build/dist/angular.min.js
[INFO] Registered manifest into CMPaaS: https://deploy-apixyz.com/swdeploy/v2/manifests/demonodeserver/versions/1.0.0_20180628165604811
Your build metrics have been recorded with id demonodeserver-06-29T00:07:42.845Z and manifest_id demonodeserver-1.0.0_20180628165604811`;

console.log(log.match(/manifest_id (\S+)/)[1]);
```

The regex itself:

```
/manifest_id (\S+)/
/                 / regexes are delimited by /
 manifest_id        a literal "manifest_id "
             (   )  capture the stuff in here and put it in the match array
              \S    any non-whitespace character
                +   one or more times
```

`String.match` returns an array with the entire match at index 0 and any capture groups after that. We only care about our single group, so we grab the string at index 1.